Using a Venn diagram to determine maximum and minimum numbers of students playing certain games
Can you please tell how to solve this using concept of Venn diagram?

There are 200 students in a school. Out of these, 100 students play cricket, 50 students play hockey and 60 students play basketball. 30 students play both cricket and hockey, 35 students play both hockey and basketball, and 45 students play both basketball and cricket.
(a) What is the maximum number of students who play at least one game ?
(b) What is the maximum number of students who play all the 3 games?
(c) What is the minimum number of students playing at least one game?
(d) What is the minimum number of students who play all the 3 games ?


Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match many users' quality standards, so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. This will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

This is how I would solve it, hope it helps.
Venn diagram
Resolution

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
